# Definite article – usage of 'the' dependent on context

Tags: articles

Which of the three articles (a/an/the) would the blanks in the following sentence take?

**It is not unusual for ____ editor to tamper with _____ writer's manuscript.**

I think it should be **'an'** and **'the'** in the first and second blank respectively, but my colleagues think otherwise. Please suggest.

Comment: This is more a question for English Language, Learners - a sister site.

Comment: Sunshine, there are a few things you should know about questions on this site. This one will surely be closed or migrated. Please take [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)'s tour as well as ours. It will help you ask on-topic questions. This one, while a common question, is off-topic for several reasons. For one, it's just an "answer this" question which doesn't show your reasoning. Why do you think it is *an* and *the*? It's also very basic for this site (better at ELL). Finally, it's a *"what"* question rather than a *"why"* question; and if it were a *why*, it would be too broad.

Comment: Persuasive arguments can be made for both 'a', 'an' and 'the', depending on the precise context of your query sentence. Specifically, 'the' would be used to describe either the role of a known editor (in a specific editorial department, say), or a typological/archetypal editor or writer. Unfortunately, since no additional context is present, I am unable to supply a more definite answer.